# Arc Length in 3D space

Tags: 3d, arc-length

So given a function $$f(x,y)=x^3+30xy+2y^3,$$ I am able to find the maximum value in a specific region. However, I need to be able to calculate the distance that would be traversed by a particle moving between the origin and the maximum, as if it were hypothetically climbing and descending the function.

Basically I need to find the arc length of the function, along the path between the origin and the maximum point. How would I go about doing this?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There might be several paths along the surface between $(0,0,f(0,0))$ and the point on the surface where $f$ achieves its maximum value.  Do you want the shortest path, or just any path?

Comment: any path is fine, I don't need to know the shortest distance. I was thinking that the easiest path would be one where the projection in the xy plane was a straight line

Comment: Good thinking.  I work out a good piece of it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not interested in any particular path on the surface joining $(0,0,f(0,0))$ to the point on the surface where $f$ achieves its maximum value, then let's just consider a straight line in the plane that joins $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$, where I'm assuming that it's at $(a,b)$ where $f$ achieves its maximum value.  Here's our line, parametrically: $c(t):=(at,bt)$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$.  Then $$\tilde{c}(t):=(at,bt, (at)^{3}+30abt^{2}+2(bt)^{3})$$ is a path on the graph of $f$ that joins $(0,0,f(0,0))$ to the highest point on the graph.  Find the length of this curve by computing the following, using standard calculus $1$ methods (you may or may not need trig substitution; I haven't worked it out that far): $$\int_{0}^{1}||\tilde{c}'(t)||dt=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+[3(at)^{2}+60abt+6(bt)^{2}]^{2}}dt$$

Comment: This is surely the way to try. I just feel like pointing out that the resulting integral may be nasty. After all the integrand is the square root of a quartic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, that might be true.  But did you say that you knew exactly at which point $f$ achieves its maximum?  That is, do you already know that $a$ and $b$ should be?  That might simplify your computations, especially if one of them is $0$.